# update query problem

Tags: mysql

i have three tables on mysql database which are:

> **RECHARGE** with these columns: rid, **uid**,res_id, agent_id, batch_id, rcard_order, serialno, email,
>   **units**, bankid, paydate, slipno, rpin, amtpd, bonus, description,
>   crSender, crSenderId,
>   transaction_ref,rechargeDate,
>   processed
>
> **SENT** with these columns: sendid, **uid**, res_id, recipients, **volume**, ffdaily, message, sender, msgtype, flash, mob_field, wapurl,
>   date
>
> **BILL** with these columns: bid, **uid**, email, **unitBals**, lastusedate

The question is these:i want a query that will subtract the sum of **volume** in SENT table from **units** in RECHARGE table and use the result to update the **unitBals** column on **BILL** table where the primary key joining the three tables is their **uid**.

i used this query but it is not giving me the same answer as when i sum(volume) and subtract it from sum(units) separately doing the calculation on my own

```
update bill set unitbals = (SELECT sum( recharge.units ) - sum( sent.volume )
                            FROM sent, recharge
                            WHERE sent.uid = recharge.uid)
where email = 'info@dunmininu.com'
```

Comment: Show us the query that works how you expect, and its output.

Comment: If you have the freedom to alter the tables, consider moving the aggregate information into separate tables entirely.  Then you can simply re-derive the information as needed using count().

Comment: I disagree. Redundant data is bad news. If you store both the individual values and the total, then you create the possibility that the two could be inconsistent, and that asking the same question two different ways could give two different answers. If data is only stored once, of course it could be wrong, but there's one place to look and one place to fix if it's wrong. Not to mention that there's only one place to update when the data changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here. First, from the fact that you are using sum, I take it that there can be more than one Recharge record for a given Uid and more than one Sent record for a given Uid. If this is true, then when you do the join, you are not getting all the Recharges plus all the Sents, you are getting every combination of a Recharge and a Sent.

For example, suppose for a given Uid you have the following records:

```
Recharge:
Uid  Units
42   2
42   3
42   4

Sent
Uid  Volume
42   1
42   6
```

Then a query

```
select recharge.units, sent.volume
from recharge, sent
where recharge.uid=sent.uid
```

will give

```
Units  Volume
2      1
2      6
3      1
3      6
4      1
4      6
```

So doing sum(units)-sum(volume) will give 18-21 = -3.

Also, you're doing nothing to connect the Uid of the Sent and Recharge to the Uid of the Bill. Thus, for any given Bill, you're processing records for ALL uids. The Uid of the Bill is never considered.

I think what you want is something more like:

```
update bill
set unitbals = (SELECT sum( recharge.units ) from recharge where recharge.uid=bill.uid)
  - (select sum(sent.volume) from sent where sent.uid=bill.uid)
where email='info@dunmininu.com';
```

That is, take the sum of all the recharges for this uid, minus the sum of all the sents.

Note that this replaces the old value of Unitbals. It's also possible that you meant to say "unitbals=unitbals +" etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot you actually gave me the right answer to my question.I've tried the query it actually solve the problem.Please i will like to be able to contact you later in case i have any other problem later.This is my email kayodemoaku2002@yahoo.com.you can add me on facebook or just send an email to my box so that i can have your email.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need separate sum in the two tables:

```
update bill
set unitbals =
    ( SELECT sum( recharge.units )
      FROM recharge
      WHERE bill.id = recharge.uid
    ) -
    ( SELECT sum( sent.volume )
      FROM sent
      WHERE bill.id = sent.id 
    ) 
where email = 'info@dunmininu.com'
```